# Problem while seleting Distinct item in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have my table schema and data something like this

```
CompanyCategoryId   SubCategoryId   CategoryId  CompanyId
      44                   22          1            7
      45                   23          1            7
      46                   24          1            7
      47                   10          2            7
      48                   11          2            8
      49                   12          2            8
      50                   16          2             7
```

You can refer this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596777/getting-count-from-sql-tables.)** for more details. What I want is to display the distinct company information on the basis of the categoryId here. For example for CategoryId 2 we 7 and 8. But my query returns 4 companies. If I use distinct keyword , then it gives an error that filteration is possible on the data type Text, as one of the required column is of type text.

Please help me out. My query

```
-- GET ALL COMPANIES REGISTERED IN THIS MONTH
DECLARE @Last30Day as date
SET @Last30Day = GETDATE() - 30
SELECT   DISTINCT   tbl_Company.CompanyName, tbl_Company.Website, tbl_Company.Email, tbl_Company.Profile,
           (ISNULL(tbl_Company.Address,'') + ', '+ISNULL(tbl_Company.City,'')+', '+ISNULL(tbl_Company.State,'')) AS Address, 
           tbl_Company.Phone1, tbl_Company.Mobile1
FROM         tbl_Company INNER JOIN
                      tbl_Company_Category_Map ON tbl_Company.CompanyId = tbl_Company_Category_Map.CompanyId
WHERE     (tbl_Company_Category_Map.CategoryId = 2) AND tbl_Company.RegistrationDate BETWEEN @Last30Day AND GETDATE()
```

**Error:** Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Why are you using a `TEXT` field to store a single character?

Comment: Profile is not a single character field. Its holds company profile data as text, in plain text or parsed html tags.

Comment: It is a column of tbl_Company defined - Profile - text - to hold company profile

Comment: Can you show your **ACTUAL** query then, including the field that is causing the error?  Why would you omit it?

Comment: Will adding `AND tbl_Company_Category_Map.CategoryId =2` help?

Comment: @Amran: if a company appears in 2 categories, like company with `CompanyID=1`, should it be shown twice?

Comment: @ypercube = so i am using distinct company id, but it throws exception as a column of type text, is so called not comparable

Comment: why negative... if the guy doesnt knows the answer, then he should keep himself away... AH.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the distinct from the main query and use it in a sub query against tbl_Company_Category_Map instead. If you have any filtering conditions against tbl_Company_Category_Map you should add those in the sub query.

```
select C.CompanyName -- extra fields here
from tbl_Company as C
  inner join (
               select distinct CompanyId
               from tbl_Company_Category_Map
               --where ? = ?
             ) as M
    on C.CompanyId = M.CompanyId
```

Comment: Thanks dude its working....If i am right the my filter condition will be at the commented where section...

Comment: @AmRan - Yes, the filter against CategoryId should be in the sub query but the filter against RegistrationDate should be, as before, in the main query.