# Getting count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting count from sql tables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596777/getting-count-from-sql-tables)

I have already asked earlier on same data and tables but this time requirement is slight different. So please do not vote it to close or downvote. 
I have 4 tables, as displayed in image 3 tables and another is tbl_Company.:
[image]

Now in the map table, the primary keys of the rest three tables. Also in table sub category we have various childs of category, marked with category id 2, but if you see in map we have only 4 items with categoryid 2 and has two unique companies 7 and 8.

So what I want is to display when a category is chosen, all its subcategories will get listed with the number of companies. Like in map table cat id 2 has 4 rows and has 12 sub cats (actually in table its 44). SO my output will have all 44 subcat with displaying 4 sub cat has companies and rest 0. Something like this

```
SubCategoryName  TotalCompanies
---------------  --------------
Badges, Emblems  0
Fashion scarves  1
…                …
```

and so on.

I used this query

```
SELECT     tbl_SubCategory.Name AS SubCategoryName, TotalCompanies = (Select COUNT(CompanyId) From tbl_Company_Category_Map WHERE CategoryId=2 )
FROM       tbl_Category RIGHT JOIN
                      tbl_SubCategory ON tbl_Category.Id = tbl_SubCategory.CategoryId
                      LEFT JOIN 

                      tbl_Company_Category_Map ON tbl_SubCategory.Id = tbl_Company_Category_Map.SUbCategoryId 
WHERE     (tbl_Category.Id = 2)
Group By tbl_SubCategory.Name
ORDER BY tbl_SubCategory.Name
```

but it returns me 4 companies for all 44 subcategories where as my actual output should be only 4 rows should have companies and rest 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular query doesn't seem to require the `tbl_Category` table:

```
SELECT
  SubCategoryName = tbl_SubCategory.Name,
  TotalCompanies  = COUNT(DISTINCT ccm.CompanyId)
FROM tbl_SubCategory sc
  LEFT JOIN tbl_Company_Category_Map ccm ON sc.Id = ccm.SubCategoryId
WHERE sc.CategoryId = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using correlated query? A correlated query is a sub query using a value of a column outside the sub query, in the main query. It would look something like this:

```
      SELECT     
        tbl_SubCategory.Name AS SubCategoryName, 
        TotalCompanies = (
          Select 
            COUNT(CompanyId) 
          From 
            tbl_Company_Category_Map 
          WHERE 
            CategoryId = tbl_Category.Id) -- Here, it will count using the current cat_id
      FROM       
        tbl_Category 
          RIGHT JOIN tbl_SubCategory 
            ON  tbl_Category.Id = tbl_SubCategory.CategoryId
          LEFT JOIN tbl_Company_Category_Map 

            ON tbl_SubCategory.Id = tbl_Company_Category_Map.SUbCategoryId  
      WHERE     
        (tbl_Category.Id = 2) 
      Group By 
        tbl_SubCategory.Name 
      ORDER BY 
        tbl_SubCategory.Name
```

Comment: Sorry for that, but there is a parenthesis that is commented...!

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'tbl_Category.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If I use it in group by of main statement, it shows 4 for all rows.

Comment: Took care of that commented parenthesis.  Probably doesn't address @AmRan's issue though.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a group by with rollup :

```
    SELECT     tbl_SubCategory.Name, tbl_Company_Category_Map.Company_ID,count(tbl_Category.Id)
    FROM       tbl_Category 
    RIGHT JOIN tbl_SubCategory ON tbl_Category.Id = tbl_SubCategory.CategoryId
   LEFT JOIN  tbl_Company_Category_Map ON tbl_SubCategory.Id = tbl_Company_Category_Map.SUbCategoryId 
    WHERE     (tbl_Category.Id = 2)
    Group By Rollup(tbl_SubCategory.Name,tbl_Company_Category_Map.Company_ID)
    ORDER BY tbl_SubCategory.Name
```

A little more information about the result set the count for just sub cats will have a null for the company id.